# How to attach a Click event on origin and destination markers of agm-directions?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, agm-map, agm-direction

I have to display a custom panel above the maps to show details on click of origin and destination marker.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R0KK.png)

Comment: please elaborate with images

Comment: Hello Welcome to Stack overflow , Please take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and How to Ask. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducile](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your attempt, input and expected output.

Comment: you must be getting some events on click of origin and destination, use those events and a flag with *ngIf to show this custom component

Comment: Can u provide an example for those events ? @ShlokNangia

Comment: depends on what map are you using, whatever it is check its documentation it must be emiting some event on click/selection

Comment: here are 2 maps library you can use in angular https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-worldmap and  https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/maps/getting-started/

Comment: @ShlokNangia I am using this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/agm-direction

Comment: check ...d.ts file in your node modules under this library, you will see supported functions with comments what they do, please try to find it there